# Why form is fetching all data when i dont give any input?

Tags: php, ajax

This is index.php . when i give a input, it fetch the specific name and year. that's OK . but when i submit the form ,without any input it gives all the name of the movie and years but i don't want that ,the user can not show all the data saved in the database. i gave priventdefault() method but it's not working. how can i solve this problem ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ajax</title>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">



            $(function() // this function excited if the jquery is ready i mean after jquery successfully loaded
            {
                function loaddata()
                {

                    var moviename= $("#moviename").val(); // read moviename value and assign;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "query.php",
                        data: {
                            name:moviename // there is no variable name so you have to assign the moveiname to name vairable ;
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                           $("#result").html(data);

                        }

                    });

                }


                $("#submit").click(function(event) // Click Event Listener.
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    loaddata()
                });
            });



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <p>Enter movie name </p>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="moviename" id="moviename" placeholder="Enter Movie Name" required autocomplete="off">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search"/>
            <!-- if you want ot use jquery you have to use event listener. like $("#submit").click(function(event){}); code from line 31 to 35 -->
        </form>
        <br>

        <div id="result">

        </div>

    </body>
</html
```

///this is query.php

```
<?php

include 'dbcon.php';

$name =isset($_GET['name'])?$_GET['name']:'';


$query = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE name like '%$name%'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$row['year']."</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: if name is empty then you're finding things `like '%%'` which matches everything. Best method is to put the query inside a `if (!empty(filter_input(INPUT_GET,"name")) { /* do query */ } else { /* return nothing */ }`

Answer (score 3):

Execute the query only if $name is not null.

```
if(!empty($name)) { 
  $query = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE name like '%$name%'");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$row['year']."</p>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$name =isset($_GET['name'])?$_GET['name']:'';

if(!empty($name)){
$query = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE name like '%$name%'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$row['year']."</p>";
}
}
```

in javascript

```
     var moviename= $("#moviename").val(); // read moviename value and assign;
    if(moviename){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "query.php",
                            data: {
                                name:moviename // there is no variable name so you have to assign the moveiname to name vairable ;
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                               $("#result").html(data);

                            }

                        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In query.php, you always assign empty string to `$name` in the line if empty 'name' value passed into query.php

```
$name =isset($_GET['name'])?$_GET['name']:'';.
```

So query will return you all the results in db as `$name` is an empty string and matches with all the data in db.

You can validate if $name is empty, not to run the query.